# Delphi+iOS: How to include iOS Extension (.appex) to a FMX-App?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, ios-app-extension

Is there a solution for adding App Extensions to a Delphi / FMX project?

Actually it isn’t possible to add iOS Application Extensions (f. e. share- or notifcations-extension) to an Delphi/FMX-App directly. Is there any way to include the Xcode-created extension into the Delphi Project?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blog.grijjy.com/2018/11/15/ios-and-macos-app-extensions-with-delphi/